# How to make pop up modal shows once a day or hours

Tags: javascript

I know there is a lot of answers about this but i cant seem to implement it with my code. What i want to do is when the user open the homepage a recommendation pop up will only show once a day or hours. Any help and suggestion is greatly appreciated.

This is the code in launching the pop up modal on page load.

```
<?php 
    if(mysqli_num_rows($check_ip) > 0 ) 
    { 
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#myModal").modal('show');
            });
        </script>
    <?php 
    } 
    ?>
```

This is the code for pop up modal

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Welcome back! Here's our recommended speakers for you.</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

    <?php
    $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 

    $check_ip =  mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT ip_address FROM reservations WHERE ip_address = '$user_ip'");

    $history_data = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE ip_address = '$user_ip'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($history_data);
    $topic = $row['topic'];
    $ip_address = $row['ip_address'];

    $select_speakers = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM speakers WHERE speaker_specialization1 = '$topic' OR speaker_specialization2 = '$topic' OR speaker_specialization3 = '$topic' ORDER BY speaker_reservedcount DESC LIMIT 3");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_speakers))
    {
        echo '
        <a href="speakerProfile.php?id='.$row["id"].'">
                        <div class=" col-sm-4 ">
                            <div class="thumbnail"><img class="speakers-image" src="img/'.$row["speaker_image"].'" style="height:150px; min-width:100%;"/>
                                <div class="caption" style="max-height:270px; min-width:100%" >
                                <center>
                                    <h3 class="speakers-name" style="font-weight:bold; margin: 2px 10px -6px 10px;">'.$row["speaker_fullname"].'</h3>
                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="speaker-topics" style="margin-top:-20px;">
                                        <p style="text-transform: capitalize;">'.$row["speaker_specialization1"].'</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="speaker-topics">
                                        <p style="text-transform: capitalize;">'.$row["speaker_specialization2"].'</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="speaker-topics">
                                        <p style="text-transform: capitalize;">'.$row["speaker_specialization3"].'</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <hr>
                                    <p class="speakers-name" style="margin:-10px 0px 5  px 0px;">Reserved Count: '.$row["speaker_reservedcount"].'</p>
                                </center>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
        </a>
        ';  
    }
?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i know this is not much but it might help somebody who has a problem like this. This how i do it

```
<?php 
    if(mysqli_num_rows($check_ip) > 0 && isset($_SESSION["popUp"]) == false) 
    {
    $_SESSION["popUp"] = "true";
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#myModal").modal('show');
            });
        </script>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
```